# Create empty Json body for HttpEntity

Tags: java, jackson

So I can't figure out this seemingly simplest problem. I want to create HttpEntity where header has content-type application/json with body being an empty Json object:

```
{}
```

Right all I have available is Jackson, however no matter what I build (tried JsonNodeFactory.instance.nullNode() and ObjectNode with null object), it cant seem to create proper empty Json object. String "{}" or null doesn't work either.
Any ideas?

Edit: guys...I'm sorry for wasting your time, turns out API I was calling was returning incorrect bad request response (400) for the wrong reasons. The request was actually correct. I'll just accept first correct answer

Comment: Would be good to provide your sample code.

Comment: You can try something like this: {"dummy": ""}. If dummy doesn't represent a valid property from your body object, you will get an empty one. It's ugly though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way is to use the `ObjectMapper` to create an empty
JSON [`ObjectNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html) and then serialize it:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode obj = mapper.createObjectNode();

String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);  // yields "{}"
```

There is no need for `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

```
/**
 * Produce an empty HttpEntity
 */
public HttpEntity<String> getJsonEntityEmpty() {
    HttpEntity<String> entity = null;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    String requestJson;
    requestJson = "{}";
    entity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestJson,headers);

    return entity;
}
```